# BLE Peripheral created by CoreBluetooth running on my Mac cannot be discovered by iPhone. But it can be discovered by Android Phone

Tags: ios, swift, macos, core-bluetooth

Here's the process of creating the Peripheral:

```swift
    // Create a CBPeripheralManager object
    let peripheralManager = CBPeripheralManager()

    // Create a CBMutableService object to represent the service
    let service = CBMutableService(type: CBUUID(string: "0003ABCD-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B0131"), primary: true)

    // Create a CBMutableCharacteristic object to represent the read characteristic
    let readCharacteristic = CBMutableCharacteristic(
        type: CBUUID(string: "00031201-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B0130"),
        properties: .read,
        value: nil,
        permissions: .readable
    )

    // Create a CBMutableCharacteristic object to represent the write characteristic
    let writeCharacteristic = CBMutableCharacteristic(
        type: CBUUID(string: "00031202-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B0130"),
        properties: .write,
        value: nil,
        permissions: .writeable
    )


    // Set the peripheral manager's delegate
    peripheralManager.delegate = self


    let advertisementData = [CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey: "BLE Serial", CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey: [service.uuid]] as [String : Any]

    peripheralManager.startAdvertising(advertisementData)

    // ...

    // MARK: - CBPeripheralManagerDelegate
    func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager) {
        if peripheral.state == .poweredOn {
            // Add the characteristics to the service
            service.characteristics = [readCharacteristic, writeCharacteristic]

            // Add the service to the peripheral manager
            peripheralManager.add(service)
        }
    }
```

I tried run this program on mac and iPhone.

On my Android phone, the peripheral can be discovered, connected and do read/write jobs. However it can't be discovered by iPhone (while running on mac) or by mac (while running on iPhone).

Comment: Show the code you are using to discover the peripheral on iOS/macOS

Comment: @Paulw11 I didn't use any code. Just scan Bluetooth in the system settings.

Comment: System settings will not discover BLE peripherals.  You need an app using core Bluetooth to scan for your peripheral's advertised service.